# select following sibling text whose ancestor node contains specific child node

Tags: xpath

I want to select a  text of the node whose ancestor is td with input tag as a child node:

Input is:

```
<tr>
    <td width="1"><input type="checkbox" name="marketCodes" value="AE01" onclick="facetCheckboxClicked(this)"></td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">Defense &amp; Security&nbsp;(1028)</td>
    <td width="1"><input type="checkbox" name="marketCodes" value="AE02" onclick="facetCheckboxClicked(this)"></td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">Geotechnologies (96)</td>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;">Aircraft Products & Services (594)</td>
</tr>
```

Expected output is:

```
 Defense &amp; Security&nbsp;(1028)
 Geotechnologies (96)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
//td[preceding-sibling::td[1]/input]/text()
```